# ColdFusion 2016 CFChart issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfchart

I have an application that we are migrating from ColdFusion 9 to ColdFusion 2016.
I am having an issue on a page that creates 6 charts and saves them as images on the server.

The system will generate some of the images but then I get a message:

> Encountered code generation error while compiling script: generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit.

I am not sure how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you limit the amount of data being included in your charts?

Comment: What is the file extension on the image files?

Comment: we are saving everything as png files

Comment: I could limit the data but we tried that and that did not solve it.

Comment: is there the abity to right the image and then start a new process to create the next one?  LIke a flush command?

Comment: Question... my client has not bought a full license of CF yet so its the developer verson- not sure if that has any bearing in this issue.

Comment: they will purchase the full licence when we start the migration process. currently code review

Comment: If you can add some of the code where you are trying to generate the images and point out the line where the error is generated from someone could help you figure out a work around for this.